# How to differentiate $-x^3(3x^4-2)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

What am I doing wrong?

$-x^3*d/dx(3x^4-2)+(3x^4-2)*d/dx(-x^3)$
$-x^3(12x^3-2)+(3x^4-2)(-3x^2)$
$-12x^9+2x^3-9x^6+6x^2$

When just using the power rule it comes out to be $-21x^6+6x^2$

Comment: You multiplied incorrectly in going from the second line to the third. Note for example that $(x^3)(x^3)=x^6$. It is not $x^9$.  Also, the derivative of $3x^4-2$ is not $12x^3-2$.

Comment: how would I get rid of the -2x^3?

Comment: There is no $-2x^3$. The derivative of $3x^4-2$ is $12x^3$.

Comment: you just ignore the constant?

Comment: The derivative of a constant wrt any variable is always zero.

Answer (score 1):

In the second line, the derivative of $3x^4-2$ should be $12x^3$, not $12x^3-2$.  For the derivative of $-2$ is $0$.

In addition, there is a mistake  in going from the second line to the third. Note that $(x^3)(x^3)=x^6$. It is not $x^9$.

Answer (score 0):

1.$$(-x^3(3x^4-2))'=(-x^3)'(3x^4-2)+(-x^3)(3x^4-2)'=$$
$$=-3x^2(3x^4-2)-x^3\cdot12x^3=-9x^6+6x^2-12x^6=6x^2-21x^6$$
2.$$(-x^3(3x^4-2))'=(2x^3-3x^7)'=6x^2-21x^6$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\overbrace{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[-x^3\left(3x^4-2\right)\right]= -x^3\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(3x^4-2\right)+\left(3x^4-2\right)\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(-x^3\right)}^{\text{product rule}}$$

$$\equiv -x^3\left(12x^3-0\right)+\left(3x^4-2\right)\left(-3x^2\right) $$

$$\equiv -12x^6-9x^6+6x^2$$
$$\equiv  \Large \boxed{-21x^6+6x^2} \quad ,$$ which is consistent with the answer you got from the power rule.